# How do I slice a 2D numpy array using another 2D numpy array that contains indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I have a sparse matrix A that is of size (3000,3000), and I have another matrix B that is of size (83068, 2) that contains the indices of the non-zero elements of A.

Is it possible to get a resulting 2D matrix, C, such that it only includes the non-zero elements from A?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
A[B]
```

But the resulting size is (83068, 2, 3000)

Comment: `A[B[:,0], B[:,1] ]`

Comment: or `I, J = B.T; X=A[I,J]`

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs), *if one supplies to the index a tuple, the tuple will be interpreted as a list of indices*.

That's why *it is possible to use the output from the `np.nonzero()` function directly as an index since it always returns a tuple of index arrays*.

So you can use:

```
>>> A = np.array([[0, 9, 3], [8, 0, 0], [6, 7, 5]])
>>> A[np.nonzero(A)]
array([9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 5])
```

You can check that `np.nonzero()` returns a tuple:

```
>>> np.nonzero(A)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]))
```

But your `B` array has a different format, like this:

```
>>> B = np.array(np.nonzero(A)).T
>>> B
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

So you need to reformat it as a tuple with as many elements as dimensions in the `A` array, as pointed out by @hpaulj. For example:

```
>>> tuple(B.T)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]))
```

In summary:

```
>>> A[tuple(B.T)]
array([9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 5])
```

Comment: In fact `np.argwhere` which produces the (n,2) array like `B` is just `np.transpose(np.nonzero(...))`.